# Sending Java Beans From An Applet to A Servlet

Tags: java, spring, applet

I'm looking at sending a complex data type [a serialized java bean (strings, map, and an image)] from an applet to a Spring structured web application.

How would I send the bean? I'm assuming that I would create a `URLConnection`, and then send out a post with a serialized version of the bean.

How would I set up spring to catch this on the Server side? [Would I use a `@RequestParam` or `@ModelAttribute`]

Both the applet and the server have access to the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you serialize it. If it is JSON, you can use `@RequestBody`, if it is binary (base64 string), it should be `@RequestParam`, and then you should deserialize it.

Comment: Well, what type should have RequestParam take in?

Comment: if you send a base64 string, it should be `String`

Comment: Also, apparently you can use the high performance HttpInvoker from spring. [if both your client and server are using spring.]